# Why is the constant of proportionality in Gauss's law exactly $1/\epsilon_0$

Tags: electrostatics, conventions, gauss-law, si-units

$\epsilon_0$ is epsilon naught, or permittivity of free space.

Let me preface this by saying that I've just started to learn about electromagnetism. When I first saw Coulomb's law, I was incredibly confused to why the proportionality constant was exactly $1/4\epsilon_0$. Then I saw that this was derived from Gauss's law. In Gauss's law though, the constant of proportionality is $1/\epsilon_0$. Then I wondered how that is true? I researched more and find that most people derive Gauss's law from Coulomb's law. So it seem's to be more like circular reasoning?

This might be similar to this question: [What was discovered first - The Coulomb constant or Gauss law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352537/)

But I find the answer here not satisfactory in that it never explains why the constant of proportionality is $1/\epsilon_0$. I kind of get that Gauss's law is a mathematical theorem and that it comes from something called the Divergence theorem that is then applied to electrostatics. I don't understand the math because it is not at my level but I can understand why the general form of the equation is like that. What I don't get is why that formula has $\epsilon_0$ as the proportionality constant. Where did it come from?

I hope my question makes sense. To summarize: What I want to know is, why is $\epsilon_0$ in these equations and how?

Comment: I know what the permittivity of free space is, the measure of how much a material resists the electric field lines going through it. But why is that included in these equations?

Comment: But Gauss' law is $\nabla\cdot\mathbf E=4\pi\rho$, I don't see any $\epsilon_0$ there :)

Comment: @KyleKanos You mean ∇⋅E=4πkρ?

Comment: no, I did not mean that. I meant $4\pi\rho$.

Comment: @KyleKanos Im confused? Where does this formula come from?

Comment: it's Gauss' law in CGS units; $\epsilon_0$ arises due to choice of units.

Comment: @KyleKanos Ohhh I see what you mean. So ϵ0  arises because of historical reasons and our choice of units?

Answer (score 3):

Gauss's law is *not* a mathematical theorem. It is an empirical law. It is an observed fact that the total flux out of a surface is equal to a constant times the contained charge. You cannot derive this constant ($\epsilon_0$) from pure math alone. At least, not with any current theory - some physicists hope that we might one day find a theory of the universe that explains all the constants we see in nature. But so far, Gauss's law is an observed fact, not an essential consequence of any mathematical theorem.

Coulomb's law is just the same. It's a mathematical equation that we observe works for describing reality.

*If* we assume Coulomb's law, then we can derive Gauss's law (in the way you allude to, using the divergence theorem). *If* we assume Gauss's law, we can derive Coulomb's. In some sense, they encode the same information, and so it is not surprising that they both have the same constant $\epsilon_0$ in them. But ultimately, you must start from one or the other. Neither they, nor the constant $\epsilon_0$, can be derived from pure math.

At some level, you can't ask "why" they're true. They're true because that's how we've discovered the universe happens to function.

(Also, to clear up some potential confusion: there *is* a related mathematical theorem that is sometimes called "Gauss's theorem" - and that's the divergence theorem that you mention. This theorem has many applications in electromagnetism, but it does *not* contain $\epsilon_0$, and it is *not* the same as the "Gauss's law" that physicists refer to.)

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE!  I’ve helped with your LaTeX, which is recommended for readability.  If you click on “Edit”, you can see what the input looks like.

Comment: So where does e0 come from? Did it come from experimentation? Like did at one point in time we had a Gauss law that had the constant k. And then we measured it to be e0?

Comment: @Jon H So where does e0 come from? Did it come from experimentation? Like did at one point in time we had a Gauss law that had the constant k. And then we measured it to be e0?

Comment: Although I don't know the full history, that viewpoint is somewhat accurate. We didn't initially discover Coulomb's law in full - we discovered that the force between charges is linear in the charge of each body. Over time, it was hypothesized that the force varied as the inverse of the distance. Once that was hypothesized, one could simply scan over several electric charges and distances, measure the force, and try to find a k which fit the equation $F=\frac{kqQ}{r^2}$. The actual history is somewhat messier, but this is the conceptual idea.